# Get a list of objects from appsettings.json with Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

Tags: c#, json, configuration, asp.net-core

I want parse a list of object from asp.net core project appsetting.json with Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. Here is what I have tried. But I am getting result of null. Did I do something wrong or it is not supported?

```
using Xunit;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Test;

namespace Tests
{
    public class ConfigTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            string json = @"{
                                'Logging':  {
                                    'IncludeScopes':  false,
                                        'LogLevel':  {
                                            'Default':  'Warning'
                                        }
                                },

                                'other': 'blah',
                                'boxes': [
                                    {
                                        'id': '1',
                                        'code': '1234'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'id': '2',
                                        'code': '0001'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'id': '3',
                                        'code': '5678'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }";

            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            var jsonConfigSource1 = new JsonConfigurationSource { FileProvider = TestStreamHelpers.StringToFileProvider(json) };

            configurationBuilder.Add(jsonConfigSource1);
            var Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            var section = Configuration.GetSection("boxes");
            Boxes result = section.Get<Boxes>();
        }

        public class Boxes
        {
            public List<Box> boxes;
        }

        public class Box
        {
            public string id;
            public string code;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am not familiar with Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, but reading [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationsection#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationSection_GetSection_System_String_) it returns an interface type `IConfiguration`, make your class implement that interface ?

Comment: I faced similar issue. It's much easier to parse such file with `Json.NET`. `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` cann't handle arrays properly.

Comment: Use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.  Something like: var boxes = Config.GetSection("boxes").Get<List<Box>>().